# Installing node-xmpp on window 7

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp

I have `node --version v0.8.22` on Windows 7. I am trying to install `node-xmpp` with the command, `npm install node-xmpp`. I have installed express, log4js and socket.io with `npm install`, but node-xmpp is throwing the following error.

```
786 info preuninstall node-xmpp@0.3.2
787 info uninstall node-xmpp@0.3.2
788 verbose true,C:\www\resume-bootstrap\src\node_modules,C:\www\resume-bootstrap\src\node_modules unbuild node-xmpp@0.3.2
789 info postuninstall node-xmpp@0.3.2
790 error node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
790 error `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
791 error Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script.
791 error This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
791 error not with npm itself.
791 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
791 error     node-gyp rebuild
791 error You can get their info via:
791 error     npm owner ls node-expat
791 error There is likely additional logging output above.
792 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
793 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-xmpp"
794 error cwd C:\www\resume-bootstrap\src
795 error node -v v0.8.22
796 error npm -v 1.2.14
797 error code ELIFECYCLE
798 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any idea's what this means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have installed the prerequisites first.
Take a look at the installation instructions for https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Since they are a bit confusing, I'll list them again here:

1. Uninstall any Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable you have installed.
2. Install Python 2.7.3
3. Install Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 (Express)
4. Install Windows 7 64-bit SDK
5. Install the compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1
6. Install Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012 for Windows Desktop (Express)
7. Install libexpat from http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/

This worked perfectly for me on 64-bit Win7. If you use the 32-bit version, then skip points 4 and 5.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll accept the answer once I test it.